# regex expression string dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make regular expressions work with dictionary?

Example:

```
my_log:
Received block blk_-967145856473901804 of size 67108864 from /10.250.6.191
Received block blk_8408125361497769001 of size 67108864 from /10.251.70.211

My dictionary:
key_log = {"Received block (.*) of size ([-]?[0-9]+) from (.*)": 1}

My code:
for line in my_log:
        key_id = key_log[my_log]
        print (key_id)
```

My code is not working?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to print lines which only match your regex ??

Comment: Thanks! trying save my_log in to csv file, and if string in my_log match my_dictionary then my code write "1" into my csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an ENUM instead of a dictionary to do it. Below is the code:

```
import re
import csv
from enum import Enum

#regex model
class Regex(Enum):
    ONE = "Received block (.*) of size ([-]?[0-9]+) from (.*)"
    TWO = "some other regex"

    @classmethod
    def match_value(cls, value):
        for item in cls:
            if re.match(pattern=item.value, string=value):
                return item

def main():
    with open(file='source.log', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            _match = Regex.match_value(value=line)
            if _match is not None:
                if _match.name == 'ONE':
                    with open(file='target.csv', mode='a') as csv_file:
                        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                        csv_writer.writerow([1])
                if _match.name == 'TWO':
                    with open(file='target.csv', mode='a') as csv_file:
                        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                        csv_writer.writerow([2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```