# python regex: create dictionary from string

Tags: python, regex

I have a sting containing multiple informations which I want to save in a dictionary:

```
s1 = "10:12:01    R1 3    E44"
s2 = "11:11:01    R100    E400"

pattern = "\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\,\d+)?" + \
          " +" + \
          "[0-9A-Za-z _]{2}([0-9A-Za-z _]{1})?([0-9A-Za-z _]{1})?" + \
          " +" + \
          "[0-9A-Za-z _]{2}([0-9A-Za-z _]{1})?([0-9A-Za-z _]{1})?$"

# --> 

d1 = {"time" : "10:12:01",
      "id1" : "R1 3", 
      "id2" : "E44"}

d2 = {"time" : "11:11:01",
      "id1" : "R100", 
      "id2" : "E400"}
```

is there a way doing this directly with python re?

Note: I'm aware that there is a similar question here: [regex expression string dictionary python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930163/regex-expression-string-dictionary-python), however the formulation is not precisly pointing to what I expact as answer.

Comment: If you want regex to directly return a dict, no.

Comment: [Named groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) will make it easier, but I'm not aware of a way to directly return a map from a regex result.

Comment: Your d1 and d2  don't match with s1 and s2, and you can use whitespaces to split the string, check my anwer below @OliverWilken

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh: Thanks, I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = "(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\,\d+)?) +(?P<id1>[0-9A-Za-z_]{2}([0-9A-Za-z1-9_]{1})?([0-9A-Za-z_]{1})?) +(?P<id2>[0-9A-Za-z_]{2}([0-9A-Za-z1-9_]{1})?([0-9A-Za-z_]{1})?$)"
>>>
>>> s1 = "10:12:01    R123    E44"
>>> print(re.match(pattern, s1).groupdict())
{'time': '10:12:01', 'id1': 'R123', 'id2': 'E44'}
```

Comment: if you change the pattern to `pattern = "(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\,\d+)?) +(?P<id1>[0-9A-Za-z _]{2}([0-9A-Za-z1-9 _]{1})?([0-9A-Za-z _]{1})?) +(?P<id2>[0-9A-Za-z _]{2}([0-9A-Za-z1-9 _]{1})?([0-9A-Za-z _]{1})?$)"`
 it works

Answer (score 1):

If the information is cleanly divided by whitespaces, why not use that information to split the string by whitespace and create the resultant list of dictionaries.
If we have multiple whitespaces, we can ignore those whitespaces while splitting using [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

```
import re

#List of strings
li = [ "10:12:01    R1 3    E44", "11:11:01    R100    E400"]

#List of kyes
keys = ['time', 'id1', 'id2']

#Create the dictionary from keys from keys listand values obtained by splitting string on 2 or more whitespaces
result = [{keys[idx]:re.split(r'\s{2,}', s)[idx] for idx in range(len(keys))} for s in li]

print(result)
```

The output will be

```
[
{'time': '10:12:01', 'id1': 'R1 3', 'id2': 'E44'}, 
{'time': '11:11:01', 'id1': 'R100', 'id2': 'E400'}
]
```

Comment: there might be white spaces in the id as well. I will edit my question to make that clear

Comment: How many whitespaces? Please include all possible variations of the string

Comment: I have updated my example to consider your updated example, please check again @OliverWilken :)